# OAuth and external auth providers

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0, owin, katana

I am building WebAPI on OWIN that needs authorization. I implemented OAuth 2.0 and I am really happy with it. For now, there is a grant_type "password" authentication implemented and now I need a way to use external authentication systems, i.e. Facebook, Google, etc.

The scenario I am trying to figure out is this:

1. iOS/Android app authorizes user with Facebook using native libraries and get Facebook access_key
2. I should get that access_key to my OAuth OWIN backend
3. Test the access key with Facebook API
4. Get user_id
5. Then map the user_id with a user in my system
6. Issue Identity Token for that particular user

Am I conceptually right and if so, how should I implement this in OAuth pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

That is how I would do it.  To implement it, you will need the Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook nuget package.

Here is a nice article that explains how to use the package.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/get-more-information-from-social-providers-used-in-the-vs-2013-project-templates.aspx?PageIndex=2

Basically, in your owin startup class, you add a call to app.UseFacebookAuthentication();

Then get the IPrincipal from HttpContext and configure it.

Comment: I took a different approach and FYI, I've checked Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook before posting the question here :) It was not the proper way to go for me, because it goes out of OAuth pipeline by using controllers and redirects.

Comment: @DovydasNavickas - I'm with you.  I want to do exactly the same thing.  How did you end up accomplishing this?  Is there an OAuth grant_type that would be appropriate for passing an external auth_token like the one you get from Facebook?

Comment: @ChrisSwain I ended up transferring auth_token from Facebook in the OAuth password field and adding another field that is not in OAuth specification called Provider. That way I can serve different providers, e.g. Facebook, Google, Twitter in a different way and it still kind of falls under the OAuth standard except for Provider field.

Comment: I'm looking into the OAuth 2 "Assertion" flow with a custom grant_type.  I believe this may be the OAuth process that will allow the flexibility needed to handle this scenario.  

Reference: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.5

Comment: Looking at the documentation now, I recall why I discredited the section 4.5. It is a good use case for a traditional "reloading" browser app, but not so good for a single page "non-reloading" app that I am developing, because it expects grant_type to be an absolute URL gotten from Authorization server and I do not need that in my case. I get the access_token from Facebook already and I need to authenticate with my API as a second step. That is why I use the grant_type=password&password={access_token}&provider=facebook. Also, I can support username/password scenario quite easily this way.